# Changing validation order in a rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, model

I have a link model that stores links to pages on the web. One of the fields is url - on that field I'm trying to perform a couple of validations, and also change it into a valid URL if its not formed right.

For example test.com would be changed to http://test.com. I also have built a custom validator to check if its a valid URL but the order is all wrong so its firing off before I get chance to add the http bit. However if the field is blank the http if firing off too soon instead of telling the user they need to input something.

Currently my validators look like:

```
before_validation :add_http
validates :url, :presence => true, :allow_nil => false, :allow_blank => false, :url => true
```

I'm sure there is a better way to achieve this. The ideal flow I think should be:

1. Check if the field is present, blank or nil
2. Check if its a valid URL
3. Add http:// to the beginning of the url if its missing
4. Check again if its now a valid url (not sure if this step is necessary depending on timing of steps 2 and 3)

Comment: Why not simply write a custom validator that takes care of everything in one go? That'll probably give you a more sensible error message as well.

Comment: Is it a good idea to have a validator that changes a value? For example I put the 'add http://' code in there too? I just assumed validators were reserved for inspection rather than action.

Comment: You'd probably want a `before_validation` hook to change a value.